# Can you name my sister?

Tags: word, poetry

I was always useless at memorising poetry and stuff. I tried putting the poems into my own words as a reminder. The problem is that I only remember my versions now and have forgotten the originals!

Here's my memory aid for a well-known bit of verse but sadly I can't remember the original version. Can you sort it out? There's bits of British slang in there so I hope you'll understand it.

*Pwhoar what a scorcher! Yes you!*

*Not bad looking and you keep yer lid on too*

*Flatulence shocks my sister's dearest friends - phew!*

**Question**

What is my sister's name?

---

Note: I have this tagged as *word*. The single-word answer will be the given name of my sister.  For example, Elizabeth.  I am not certain whether this should be described as a riddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sister's name is

> May

> Pwhoar what a scorcher! Yes you!

> Shall I compare thee to a summer's day?

> Not bad looking and you keep yer lid on too

> Thou art more lovely and more temperate.

> Flatulence shocks my sister's dearest friends - phew!

> Rough winds may shake the darling buds of May

> "darling buds" -> dearest friends, so May is your sister!